# iOS read CSV file by using CHCSVParser

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Here is my code, and the csv file is
    "Hello,Baby",Testing 
    ByeBye,Testing

When I print out the rowArray, I found that the result contain " 
    "Hello,Baby"

How can I remove it

```
- (IBAction)importToDatabase:(id)sender {
    NSString *csvFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@",NSHomeDirectory(),@"test1.csv"];
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:csvFilePath])
        NSLog(@"Exist");
    else
        NSLog(@"NOT EXIST");
    NSArray *rowArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:csvFilePath];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[rowArray objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the function `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` to replace the `"` with a blank string (see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString%3awithString%3a)). If have access to the code of the method `arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:` you can did it in there, if not you will have to iterate throw the values of your array to remove it.